# Disable code formatting for a section in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

In Eclipse with java, there is a special notation @formatter:off/on to disable/enable formatter from a section of source.
Is there some similar feature in Delphi 2010?
It's because anonymous procedures are ugly formatted:

```
begin
  Synchronize(procedure begin ShowMessage('Hi'); end);
end;
```

Comment: No, there is no way to disable sections of code from being formatted.

Comment: Although it is not possible to disable the formatter for a section of source code, there might be solutions to the specific problem you have. Can you elaborate on that in more detail?

Comment: While you can't disable formatting for a section, you can select a (different) section and only format that. If you want to format, just select the part _before_ the section, format, then the part _after_ the section and format again. More work, but I assume you don't have to reformat that often. In other words: formatting is not file-wise, you can also only format the current selection.

Comment: To get things straight: Do you mean formatting (like applying indentation based on `begin..end`, etc) or syntax highlighting (like highlighting keywords)?

Comment: You are not saying which version of Dephi you are using or which formatter. Assuming you use the one in GExperts (which might be unlikely but possible), there is {(*} and {*)}.

Comment: Upgrade is the only alternative, unless you can find a plugin which does the job. See [Delphi automatic Format Source corrupts anonymous procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15468331/576719)

Comment: If I upgrade only the formatter dll from a newer Delphi version, it works?